# UISearchBar within a UIToolbar won't show cancel button

Tags: ipad, ios, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I have a UISearchBar nested as a UIBarButtonItem within a UIToolbar.  The basic functionality works, but the cancel button and the scope bar refuse to display.  I've tried enabling them in the interface builder, and I've also tried manually calling `[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES]`, but neither method works.  Any ideas?

This is on an iPad.  I tried in iOS 3, and it doesn't work in 4.2, either.

Answer (score 11):

You need to wrap the UISearchBar with another view.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
UIView *searchBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
[searchBarContainer addSubview:searchBar];
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarContainer];
```

Answer (score 3):

You've simply hit a limitation on how UISearchBar works. One workaround is to layer the UISearchBar over the UIToolbar rather than having it genuinely live in the toolbar. This works visually because a search bar is painted just like a toolbar - their gradients are the same.

Answer (score 0):

is it really necessary to ever use a Cancel button in a search bar? Just use the textDidChange method to see if the string has been cleared and use that to do the same thing the cancel would.

Comment: so you're saying that whenever the user deletes the last character the keyboard should dismiss and editing end?  That seems like presumptuous behavior on the part of the app.